# Enqueueing scripts if a file exists

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I work with wordpress on my child theme.

My site is installed into `mydomain.xx/install`, but runs from `mydomain.xx`.

My `functions.php` **works** and looks like this:

```
<?php

/* Script in head */
function carica_scripts() {

  /* Common scripts */
  // insert scripts here, if some

  /* Page-based script */
  $pageId = get_the_ID();
  $pageType = get_post_type();
  $myBaseURL = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';

  /* Page-type scripts */ 
  if($pageType == "product") {
    wp_enqueue_script('CondAll', $myBaseURL . 'CondAll.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('CondShipping', $myBaseURL . 'CondShipping.js', array('jquery'));
  }

  /* Page-id scripts */
  if($pageId == "1") {
    wp_enqueue_script('Cond1', $myBaseURL . 'Cond1.js', array('jquery'));
  }

  if($pageId == "294") {
    wp_enqueue_script('Cond294', $myBaseURL . 'Cond294.js', array('jquery'));
  }

  if($pageId == "318") {
    wp_enqueue_script('Cond318', $myBaseURL . 'Cond318.js', array('jquery'));
  }

  if($pageId == "232") {
    wp_enqueue_script('Cond232', $myBaseURL . 'Cond232.js', array('jquery'));
  }
  /* END of page-based script */
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carica_scripts' );

?>
```

What I want to achieve is avoiding all the ifs on `$pageId`, and to auto-enqueue jQuery script `CodXXX.js` on `page id XXX` if the relative file exists in the subdirectory `/js/` of my child theme.

Comment: I found the solution. The code provided in the answer of Nathan Dawson does not work in my case (maybe it's my provider's fault). I had to make some changes, and I'm going to update my question with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by Nathan Dawson does not work in my case, I had to do some workarounds. I ended up with the following code:

```
/* Load scripts in head */
function carica_scripts() {

  /* Common scripts */

  /* END of common scripts */

  /* Page-based script */
  $pageId = get_the_ID();
  $pageType = get_post_type();
  $handle  = 'Cond' . $pageId;
  $file = $handle .'.js';
  $relPath = '/js/';
  $styleSheet_path = get_stylesheet_directory();
  $domain_base = 'mydomain.it/public_html/';
  $start_pos = strpos ( $styleSheet_path, $domain_base) + strlen ($domain_base); 
  $basePath = substr ( $styleSheet_path, $start_pos); // I need everything after 'mydomain.it/public_html/'
  $file_path = $basePath. $relPath . $file;
  $enqueue_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $relPath;
  $enqueue_file = $enqueue_path . $file;

  /* if page-type is ... (product, in this case) */  
  if($pageType == "product") {
    wp_enqueue_script('CondAll', $enqueue_path . 'CondAll.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('CondShipping', $enqueue_path . 'CondShipping.js', array('jquery'));
  }
  /* If page id is... (1, in this case - because page 1 is not product but I want CondAll here too) */
  if($pageId == "1") {
    wp_enqueue_script('CondAll', $enqueue_path . 'CondAll.js', array('jquery'));
  }
  /* auto load script CondXXX.js from subdir js/ if file exists */ 
  if ( file_exists( $file_path ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $enqueue_file, array( 'jquery' ) );
  }       
  /* END of page-based script */
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carica_scripts' );
```

Now the the scripts load.

Answer (score 3):

`file_exists()` expects an absolute path to a file rather than a URL.

Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the path you need. Also `get_the_ID()` shouldn't be used outside of the loop.

Example:

```
/* 
 * Enqueue CondXXX.js on page XXX if file CondXXX.js exists 
 */
function carica_scripts() {
    global $post;

    // Check we're on a page.
    if ( ! is_page() ) {
        return false;
    } 

    // Build the filename to check.
    $handle  = 'Cond' . $post->ID;
    $relpath =  '/js/' . $handle . '.js';

    // Get path + url to file.
    $file_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . $relpath;
    $file_url  = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $relpath;

    if ( file_exists( $file_path ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $file_url, array( 'jquery' ) );
    }  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carica_scripts' );
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it still doesn't work... By the way, I'm using a child theme and insert the code into functions.php of it, and `get_the_ID()` as well as `get_post_type()` appear to me to work properly. But I used your full code just in case...

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't work providing it's implemented properly. I'd probably echo the result of $file_url and make sure the file it's calling exists. Also you mentioned `get_post_type()` - are you expecting this file to be loaded on a custom post type rather than a page?

Comment: $relpath =  '/js/' . $handle . '.js'; Returned paths from directory functions do not have trailing slash.

Comment: @bobdye Not sure what you mean? The function I'm using to get the paths doesn't include a trailing slash which is why I'm adding it in the relpath variable.

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory() returns something like "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/yourtheme". Usin the $relpath in the original answer, you would get "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/yourthemejs/condxxx.js". There is a slash missing after yourtheme.

Comment: You're spot on. While I was aware that the function doesn't return a trailing slash I thought I was already adding it which is why I responded with confusion. I've since updated my code to add the slash.

Comment: @NathanDawson I'm using post_type for loading some scripts for particular post types, and works; also, I'm using a series of if on the_ID to load scripts for single post ids. The reason for I wanted to implement the code in the question is just to avoid these ifs

Comment: @NathanDawson I already noticed and fixed the trailing slash problem, but I can't get the code to work anyway... That's sad :(

Comment: @NathanDawson is it possible I get an error because I have my WP site into mydomain.xx/install and not into the root?

Comment: @bobdye I still can't get it to work; I edited the question to better explain all the stuff. Have you got any idea to help, please?

Comment: I found the solution. I'm going to update my question